# Getting the tweets with highest number of likes, retweets and comments

Tags: python, tweepy

I trying to use tweepy to filter top 10 users by the highest number of likes, retweets, and comments.

I tried using this

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#27DecBlackDay',result_type='popular').items(10):
    print(tweet.text)
```

Rather than filtering out the most popular top 10 tweets. It gives mostly less than 10 and for some searches, it does not even return anything.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> It gives mostly less than 10 and for some searches, it does not even return anything.

`.items(10` in this case represents an upper-bound not a must-have value. The requested count of ten items is the **maximum** of values that will be returned, **not the minimum**.

You aren't able to do anything in this case as it's outside of the library scope and influenced by many factors - most often due to Twitter's limits.

---

I highly suggest to check a few of the following sources for **further reading** purposes:

- [Official Twitter documentation including a statement to the `maxResults`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/search-api/faq)
- [Twitter Developer forums with a similar question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/why-when-i-ask-for-100-tweets-less-than-100-are-returned/10789)
- [Identical GitHub issue](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/560)